# django build absolute url inside a management command

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-commands

We use reverse in django to get the url eg. -

```
my_url = reverse("name_of_url", kwargs={"param":param, "param2":param2})
```

In the above case, `my_url` will be of the form `/path1/path2/..`

If I want to generate something like - `www.mysite.com/path1/path2/` we need to do the following -

```
my_url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse("name_of_url", kwargs={"param":param, "param2":param2}))
```

This will give the URL in desired format. But the trouble is, I am generating the url inside a custom management command,and don't have access to the `request` variable. Is there any way, I can generate the url in format - `www.mysite.com/path1/path2/`.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, as far as I know there's no way of doing that from a management command. As you've realized yourself, you use part of the `request` information to build the full URL, and when you launch a management command from the console there's no request.

What I've done in my projects is setting up a variable called `BASE_URL` in the `settings` with your base domain and using it to build your URL.

You can also check the sites framework: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/